# Issues with single page application

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I see a few issues with Single Page Applications (SPA). I want to know how these cases are handled.
Issues:

1. When **JavaScript is disabled** on user's browser, he won't be able to use the app.
2. Since all/most of the content is rendered by JavaScript, **search engines are not able to index** the content of our app So ranking of a site with SPA will be much lower.
3. We have only one page so **metadata can be defined on the same page** but depending upon various routes (Talking about Backbone) we may want to have **different metadata associated with different routes** so search engines can put my site up when user searches some keyword which is related to my app.

Any details am I missing ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application#Search_engine_optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on my phone so I'll keep my two cents in this short.

1. No JavaScript, no SPA for you. If an user wants the best the web can offer, you'll need some JavaScript to do that.
2. and 3. I  Look at SPA as the application within the site. If you want your SEO then put it in the welcome and product description pages. The SPA is the application. Further, worry less about SEO. If you make something good, get the word out, stop worrying about search engine tricks.